# Why cant i locate a button in selenium?

Tags: python, xpath, locate

Im coding an autofollower for Instagram and in the video i watched the person wrote that code and the program followed everyone with "Follow" in it, but for me it wont work.I already looked for different questions on stackoverflow but all the answers wont help. Look below:

```
#the method of the video i watched
a = 1
for i in range(5):
    for i in range(1, 11):
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//[button(text()="Follow")]')\
             .click()
```

I also tried various ways of the code i posted above but everything wont work. What can i do?

Errorcode:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//[button(text()="Follow")]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: you can mark your question as answered if my answer solves your question, or comment if there is something wrong about the answer :)  same for your other post that you left it without even pointing the issue.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66714883/how-do-i-increase-the-value-of-an-variable-in-a-command-line , for us to be able to further help you in the future you have to interact with answers and mark questions that are answered as answered, and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

here is the correct syntax :

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Follow"]')
```

if there are many buttons sharing the same text `Follow` and you want to click them all you can do :

```
result = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//button[text()="Follow"]')
```

then after it, loop through them and click them one by one :

```
for button in result:
    button.click()
```

Comment: I just wrote it down like u said it but its still not working and its showing me an error for the "e". Undefined variable 'e'

Comment: try `for button in result:
    button.click()` i made a typing mistake

Comment: Sadly its still not working, the error message is below. Maybe its not working with this way of button finding. 
Error message: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button class="_5f5mN       jIbKX  _6VtSN     yZn4P   ">...</button> is not clickable at point (522, 105). Other element would receive the click: <div class="RnEpo  Yx5HN     " role="presentation">...</div>